# Why does Landsat 8 Collection 2 Band 10 data has spots with no values?

Tags: remote-sensing, landsat-8, missing-data, earth-explorer

We're currently researching urban heat distributions in Germany using Landsat 8 data.

As stated in the Collection 2 Level 2 Science Product Guide, Band 10 of this product is the processed data of Landsat's thermal infrared sensors transformed into surface temperature in Kelvin.

When I download the data using the Earth Explorer or Google Earth Engine, every Picture has the same pattern of missing data on it – regardless of the time, when it was captured.

To illustrate the issue see those two images from 2013 and 2021, both with the same pattern of missing data. The 2013 image is from path 194, row 26, the 2021 image from path 193, row 26.

[image: Image from 2013 of Landsat C2 L2 Band 10 of a part of Bavaria with the characteristic stripe.]

[image: Picture of the same area with the same stripe of missing data from 2013]

Why is the data missing in this areas?

Are there any comparable products with pre-calculated surface temperature for non-US regions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Advanced Spaceborne Thermal Emission and Reflection Radiometer Global Emissivity Dataset (ASTER GED) provided by the Land Processes Distributed Active Archive Center (LP DAAC) is used in the generation of a Landsat surface temperature product. Where ASTER GED data is missing, there will be missing data in the Landsat ST product.
[image: the ASTER GED data cover 194/26]

https://www.usgs.gov/landsat-missions/landsat-collection-2-surface-temperature